# Не работают анимации UIView animate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Есть ios приложение, написанное на swift.
В этом приложение создал viewController, написанный на objective-c
В данном viewController имеются анимации UIView animate
Почему при запуске данного viewController из swift-проекта не работают анимации, хотя при запуске из objective-c проекта они работают прекрасно?

Comment: Причин может быть множество, но угадать их не видя вашего кода невозможно.

Comment: Приложите пример кода / готовый проект где воспроизводится данная проблема.